# Postfix: how to stop postfix or Ubuntu sending emails to Gmail and getting a 421-4.7.0 error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gmail, postfix

I have an Linux server (Ubuntu) in which, while setting it up, I entered my gmail address. So now, each 5 or 6 minutes, gmail servers respond to my server with the following message (appearing in the logs):

```
Sep  3 15:47:41 mainserver postfix/smtp[5404]: 9CA07314035F: to=<{myName}@gmail.com>, relay=alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[108.177.14.27]:25, delay=193543, delays=193541/0.61/0.31/0.2, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (host alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[108.177.14.27] said: 421-4.7.0 [{my ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xx}      15] Our system has detected an unusual rate of 421-4.7.0 unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our 421-4.7.0 users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been temporarily 421-4.7.0 rate limited. Please visit 421-4.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedRateLimitError to 421 4.7.0 review our Bulk Email Senders Guidelines. v11si11693915lfi.41 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

(For security purposes I replaced above my real address with {myName} and my real IP with {my ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xx})

So, Gmail is trying to protect my gmail.com email (which is obviously mine) from receiving messages sent to it by my server.

Trying to stop this behavior, I replaced my gmail address in every hosted site  with a self-hosted email address.

But, as you can see, the warnings are still appearing.

I also edited `/etc/aliases` and after

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
clamav: root
```

...I added `root:postmaster@{my.address}` hoping it will rewrite the gmail root email with the self-hosted one (here my real address is replaced with {my.address})

What do you thing I have to do to stop these mails from getting to gmail?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what's happening. The problem was the mail queue in my server.

By typing `#mailq` in the terminal, I got a list of 24 deferred emails which Gmail wasn't accepting but wasn't rejecting also with the usual code of 550 (550 Message rejected).

So the server kept trying to send these mails instead of deleting them -that's bad. That caused the notification.

I deleted these emails with

```
# postsuper -d ALL deferred
```

and the gmail notifications stopped.

Now I have to configure Postfix to delete such emails instead of keeping them in the queue.